# Recovering data from a corrupted HFS+ partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, macbook

I have an old Macbook from the year 2006, (Intel CPU)
The OS (`Mac OS X 10.6.8`) suddenly stoped working, not sure why...
So I decided to use a Ubuntu Live Boot (USB), (The CD Reader is dead)
to boot and I backup up the entire disk:
I used used an ethernet cable to conect to another computer, which has Ubuntu installed (Willy Werewolf) then I used `LinkLocalOnly` for the network conection,
Then using `sshfs` I mounted a folder of the other drive to the local desktop.
Then I used `gnome-disks` to `Create Disk Image` of the entire Hard Drive, and set the output location for the file to the mounted folder, (so it would port/pipe it directly to the other PC)
When done it said `Error reading 21 MB, they have been replaced with zeros`, but the rest of the `320 GB` Hard Drive was Backed up.

Afterwards I permanently installed `Ubuntu 15.10 (Willy Werewolf)` repartitioning the entire disk, probably killing some data, after which I began installing software, Wine, VLC, Steam, Java, and more it worked fine, a bit slow, but it booted atleast, a few installations later and a couple reboots, it started booting SLOW 5+ minutes of the purple starting screen, but without the Ubnutu logo, then it started working. I was getting slightly worried, a couple reboots later, it spent 30+ minutes booting, I was getting very worried, then another reboot later it did not boot all it did was 5 minutes of black screen, then a black screen with the text: `error: failure reading sector X from 'hd0'.` but then X was replaced by a hexadecimal number: 0x2542eaa0 for example it pumped out a few more defect sectors, including 0x0, after a while of doing that it went to a `grub` Command-Line User Interface,

I restored the Disk Image I talked about earlier, using the USB Live Boot, and sshfs + gnome-disks again, it still won't boot the original OS (OS X 10.6.8)
And some data has been corupted if it was a program or an app or some downloads, I'd say, well that sucks, **BUT** no, it doesn't see the bytes that identify the `Users` directory. I booted it with the Ubuntu Live Boot, and tried with `fsck` but it threw the following error: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6DZaBs3e)

I have no clue how I could get it back now, so please if you have an idea, please respond, thank you!
Have a nice day!

P.s. `mac os x` would not boot anymore BUT the data was still intact

Comment: it looks like your harddisk was already broken with Mac OS X on it...

Comment: `mac os x` would not boot anymore BUT the data was still intact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your harddisk was already (at least partly) broken with mac os x on it, then you created an "also broken" image of it. with using it further you completely killed the harddisk.

if there are usable data within the image, with a other working machine or live system (with support for reading HFS+ filesystem) you can maybe read some remaining data from the image by...

- using `tsk_recover` (package `sleuthkit`) to read files on the fly from your image
- mounting (`mount`) your image direct and look after your files
- or writing it via `dd` to a new/other harddisk and then connect as a normal external media

if all methods don't give you some data IMHO the last thing you can try is, <s>after mounting or writing the image to a harddisk,</s> using `photorec` (`testdisk`) to recover them... but it is unlikely that in this case it will do the trick! :-/

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! I was able to get most if not all important data back with photorec (testdisk) thank you very very VERY much!

Comment: P.s. I tried tsk_recover it only gave a bunch of emtpy folders and 19KB of text files.   Mounting it didn't show any files in the corrupter user directory.   And I tried dd but with no the same result as mounting.   also you don't have to mount it for photorec just put the image file as input in the command